# Merge bitmaps asynchronously

Tags: android, bitmap, universal-image-loader

I use `Android universal image loader` library to download images from external source. I need to merge 2 bitmaps (original + local [dynamic images] ) and show them in `ListView`.

For now I'm doing it on the UI thread, when the image downloaded listener is called, but it is really bad, slow and not recommended. Is there any way to access the processing classes so the merging can be done asynchronously and then saved by the library. Actually, I need to access the split second between bitmap being downloaded, decoded and stored. I tried to extends the `BitmapDisplayer` class, however I was unable to achieve this since, the `BitmapDisplayer` is set only once, at the initialization of the `ImageLoader` and my local images (those that need to be merged with the downloaded bitmap) change depending on the constraints, which are irrelevant for this question.

Any pointers?

Comment: "the `BitmapDisplayer` is set only once, at the initialization of the `ImageLoader`" - What do you mean by that? `BitmapDisplayer`can be set for every display task (`.displayImage(...)`)